# Finding a desired solution without using call_nth/2 multiple times or the use of findall/3?

Tags: prolog, time-complexity, meta-predicate

As far as i understand, call_nth(:Goal, ?Nth) returns the Nth solution of Goal but at the same time it secretly calculates all the previous solutions (from 1st to (N-1)th) and simply ignores them. If we wish to compare the Xth with the (X+1)th solution for every X between 1 and N-1, call_nth becomes very costly, cause it basically keeps calculating solutions which have already been calculated in previous steps. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve problems of this form, without using findall/3 of course.

(A typical example to this, would be the script below which finds the GOAL or the closest maximum to it, if GOAL doesn't exist in the predicates.)

```
num(10).
num(20).
num(30).
num(40).
num(50).

search_for_goal(GOAL,RESULT):-
    search_for_goal(GOAL,0,1,RESULT).

search_for_goal(GOAL,_,COUNTER,GOAL):-
    call_nth(num(GOAL),COUNTER),!.
search_for_goal(GOAL,CURRENT_MAX,COUNTER,RESULT):-
    call_nth(num(X),COUNTER),
    COUNTER2 is COUNTER+1,
    (  X=<CURRENT_MAX->
       search_for_goal(GOAL,CURRENT_MAX,COUNTER2,RESULT)
    ;  search_for_goal(GOAL,X,COUNTER2,RESULT)
    ).
search_for_goal(_,CURRENT_MAX,COUNTER,CURRENT_MAX):-
    \+call_nth(num(_),COUNTER).
```

Comment: `As far as i understand, call_nth(:Goal, ?Nth) returns the Nth solution of Goal` Please read it again: `True when Goal succeeded for the Nth time.`

Comment: Are you really interested in comparing **exactly** the Nth and N+1st answer? This is an extremely unusual thing to ask since the very precise order in which answers are produces is of relevance in only very rare cases - and in particular not in cases where you want to determine the maximum.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? `call_nth/2` has very specific uses, and most of the time it is called with an uninstantiated `Nth`. Not with a given `Nth`. This is **not** a predicate for beginners.

Comment: @false how could call_nth(GOAL, n) possibly know beforehand if the n-th solution exist? thus, i assume it calculates all the solutions through backtracking from 1 to n and simply returns the n-th one. My question is if there's a way, after getting the first solution, to "force" the system to jump immediately to the second solution, without recalculating the first solution - as call_nth(GOAL,2) would do.

Comment: Let me repeat: What is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SWI-Prolog, this can be achieved with Prolog Engines. To illustrate this, consider my own version of the findall/3 predicate which returns only even-numbered solutions.

```
my_findall(Templ, Goal, List) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
    engine_create(Templ, Goal, E),
    get_answers(E, List),
    engine_destroy(E)).

get_answers(E, [H|T]) :-
    /* Skip next solution. */
    engine_next(E, _),
    /* Take next solution. */
    engine_next(E, H),
    !,
    get_answers(E, T).

get_answers(_, []).
```

Querying with:

```
my_findall(X,member(X,[1,2,3,4]),Y)
```

Returns only the n'th solutions where n is even.

```
Y = [2, 4]
```